# Data is not loading from database on load (php + ajax)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, livesearch

> Note: I want this exact working [Show data from database on load](https://www.wdb24.com/show-data-from-database-on-page-load-using-ajax-php-and-jquery/)

I am making a live search using ajax all is well but there only 1 problem which I need to solve so the problem is that the ajax is not working on page load, I mean that I am getting data from URL like this .i.e, `http://localhost/basic_hackings/search.php?q=usman`, here "üsman" is data being searched. So everything is working correctly but on refresh it go away, I am also using `onload` in jQuery, but all in vain. see code from more details.

`ajax_search.php` is:

```
<?php 
$host = "localhost";
$dbUser = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "basic_hackings";

$dbConn = new mysqli($host,$dbUser,$password,$database);

if($dbConn->connect_error)
{
    die("Database Connection Error, Error No.: ".$dbConn->connect_errno." | ".$dbConn->connect_error);
}

$search_data = $_GET['q'];
$qry = "select first_name, last_name, email, phone, city, country from customers where first_namelike '%$search_data%'";

$rs = $dbConn->query($qry);

$fetchAllData = $rs->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$createTable = '<table>';

$createTable .= '<tr>';
$createTable .= '<th>First Name</th>';
$createTable .= '<th>Last Name</th>';
$createTable .= '<th>Email</th>';
$createTable .= '<th>Phone</th>';
$createTable .= '<th>City</th>';
$createTable .= '<th>Country</th>';
$createTable .= '</tr>';


foreach($fetchAllData as $customerData)
{
    $createTable .= '<tr>';
    $createTable .= '<td>'.$customerData['first_name'].'</td>';
    $createTable .= '<td>'.$customerData['last_name'].'</td>';
    $createTable .= '<td>'.$customerData['email'].'</td>';
    $createTable .= '<td>'.$customerData['phone'].'</td>';
    $createTable .= '<td>'.$customerData['city'].'</td>';
    $createTable .= '<td>'.$customerData['country'].'</td>';
    $createTable .= '</tr>';    
}

$createTable .= '</table>';

echo $createTable;

$rs->close();

$dbConn->close();

?>
```

and `ajax_search.js` is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#form1').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var search_data = $('#search_data').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "ajax_search.php/?q=" + search_data,
                type: "GET",
                data: new FormData($("#form1")[0]),
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                beforeSend: function(data) {
                    $(".main_search_content").html("");
                    $(".main_search_content").addClass("searching");
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        if (!(data == "")) {
                            $(".main_search_content").html(data);
                        }
                        else {
                            $(".main_search_content").html("Nothing Found!");
                        }
                        $(".main_search_content").removeClass("searching");
                    }, 500)
                }
            });
            history.pushState(null, null, "?q=" + search_data);
        }
    });
});
```

and here is `site.js` where I'm using `onload`, see:

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax_search.php',
        success: function(data){
            $(".main_search_content").html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: In all respects your code is really messy and horrible to maintain... think about separation of concerns... using template engines etc...and then have a much easier life as a developer

Comment: bro can u tell how to give URL in ajax if the file in back folder i mean not in current folder in predecessor folder I'm using this url: '../../../ajax_search.php', but not working?

Comment: I want this [Show data on load](https://www.wdb24.com/show-data-from-database-on-page-load-using-ajax-php-and-jquery/)

Comment: Your code is too messy to read, like B001 already stated. Use templating engines and such.

Comment: Doesn't your `$(window).on(...)` in `site.js` lack the first **event** parameter? You only have a handler. See: http://api.jquery.com/on

Comment: I can understand why your code is putting other people off, but don't let that discourage you. We all have to learn somehow. Their suggestions are correct though, a bit more structure would be nice.

Comment: Hey all I have now updated the code can u all see?

Comment: Why don't you put the code from your `$(window).on("load", function(){});` into your `$(document).ready()` instead.

Comment: @bcr666 yeah i also done that but not worked

Comment: I would put a `console.log(data);` line in your success on the `$(window).on("load",...`. I would also put in an error, just to make sure you aren't getting an error.

Comment: There is a problem in your query. You need a space before the `like`.

Comment: You are also possibly opening yourself up SQL Injection attack with that approach. You should look into using prepared statements.

Comment: It is also a trivial thing and a personal choice of mine; I like to send back JSON objects. I usually add a errorCode and errorText field to the JSON object so that when I get it back in the success, I can see there was an error and display that error to the user. If I get a good JSON data back, I use JavaScript and jQuery to create the HTML. In this case my basic html page would already have the `<table><thead><tr><th>...</tr></thead><tbody id='table-body'></tbody></table>` in it and I would just build the rows from the JSON abject and put them into the `<tbody>`.